# Инверсия по селектору

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать так, чтобы сработало нечто похожее на инверсию

```
$(".containerItems .row [data-search*='" + symbol + "']")
```

Мы берем те элементы, атрибуты которых равны введенным символам `(symbol)` на уровне подстроки.

Как сделать инверсию ? Типа..берем те элементы, где атрибуты не равны введенным символам на уровне подстроки..

Comment: @Kromster беда в том, что я понятия не имею, как это обозвать. Назвал по глупому "Инверсия по селектору".

Comment: Так уже лучше, спс

Comment: `:not()` селектор или `,not()`  метод

Comment: @teran правильно ли я понял, что `var dis = $(".containerItems .row:not([data-search*='" + symbol + "'])").length ` ? Т.е посчитать кол-во элементов где атрибут не равен символам ?

Comment: да. только у вас ранее было `.row [data=...`, то ест дочерние к строке элементы, а с not почему-то пробел пропал, то есть теперь фильтруете сами строки

Comment: Большое спасибо!